# Running bash script as a service and write to another bash script is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following problem using bash script.

Here is what I have inside the 'startup' script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp ../lib/online-store.jar:../lib/* com.online.store.Main

OnlineStorePID=$! 

if [$OnlineStorePID -ne 0] then
    echo "kill $OnlineStorePID" > shutdown
fi
```

Basically what I do, is to run a java application, get the process id and write it to another bash file. All this process works when I execute the startup script, and the 'shutdown' script file is updated successfully with a line containing 'kill processIDNumber' cmd.

Now I have tried to create a service on Ubuntu for this script using the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable online-store.service
sudo systemctl start online-store
```

When I start the service the java application starts successfully, but the shutdown script file is not updated. It seems that the 'echo "kill $OnlineStorePID" > shutdown' line is not executed. I don't get any complain errors. Does anyone knows what's the problem here.

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Online store service
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
Wants=mysql.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/Desktop/online-store-service

#path to executable. 
ExecStart=/home/user/Desktop/online-store-service/bin/startup
ExecStop=/home/user/Desktop/online-store-service/bin/shutdown

SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Minecraft to the rescue ;) https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Ubuntu_startup_script

Comment: Whats in your service file?

Comment: You don't need `execstop`   service does it for you, no need to try and manage pids yourself.

Comment: Yes u are correct, but I want to use the shutdown script file for stopping the java application.

Comment: Java will be killed anyway when the parent is.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script and run the java command like below as back ground process

```
java -cp ../lib/online-store.jar:../lib/* com.online.store.Main  >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: This works (the shutdown script is updated with the cmd) but I get an error on the startup of the service " Failed with result 'exit-code'"

Comment: provide me your shutdown script with full detail.